# -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If i needed more rows in one section than another, is there a code i could implement to do this?

I have 3 sections altogether but in one section i require 6 rows, in another only 3, and in the last perhaps 3 again.

Regards,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just implement the method in the title that returns a different number for different `section`.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (section == 0)
     return 6;
   else
     return 3;
}
```

Comment: brilliant and im guessing after else you can add else if (section == 1) and so on?

Comment: @Jon: Yes. There is nothing special in this method, any valid Objective-C code will do.

Comment: Great, works perfectly though getting a minor error; control reaches end of non-void function. But it builds ok and runs in simulator fine.

Comment: @Jon add return 0; (without any if, else or whatever) to the end of that method to get rid of that warning.